# NAN result Adruino Uno

Tags: c++, math, arduino, nan

I'm trying to do some math in Arduino and the result is NaN:

```
int Count1=1;
int Count1=1;
int Count2=2;

float Total= 0;
float n1= Count1;
float n2= Count2;

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
 Total = ((n1 / n2)*-100);
 Serial.print(Total);
}
```

Result: Total = Nan.

Can you help me with some hints ?

Answer (score 2):

hard to say what compiler you got (I do not code in Arduino framework) But I see the problem with this line:

```
Total = ((n1 / n2)*-100);
```

where `n1=1, n2=2` are `float`s  but `-100` is integer so your compiler most likely converted computation into integer `(1/2 = 0)` and then convert back to `float` which is SLOW and round off your wanted result... There are ways how to solve this

1. use floats to avoid integer math

   ```
   Total = ((n1 / n2)*-100.0);
   Total = ((n1 / n2)*-100.0f);
   ```
2. multiply first to preserve accuracy

   ```
   Total = (-100*n1)/n2;
   ```

   however this will most likely still use integers so you would have no digits after decimal point.

I would prefer to use #1 as your output is also `float`...

However all this would lead to result `0` instead of `NAN` so there might be also different problem like what datatype your `Serial.print(Total);` expects is it really `float` or its `double`?

Try this:

```
double x;
x=Total;
Serial.print(x);
```

If it makes any difference. Anyway your code is not MCVE as I see no `main` so there might be also problem in part of code you did not share.

Also common problem on Arduino is low RAM memory depending on what MCU you have I expect you got 1 or 2 KByte of RAM so if your code uses more you can easily overwrite parts of your variables (especially if you include ADAFRUIT SSD1306 LCD driver which takes alone slightly above 1KByte of RAM for itself).

Comment: in a compliance compiler `n1 / n2` must be done as float if both are floats. I suspect the OP actually used `int`s instead of floats as in the posted code

Comment: @phuclv do not expect fully compliant compiler on MCU (you would not believe what crap they capable of especially GCC) and ARDUINO framework does not use C/C++ compiler its a different language (verry similar but has syntax differences). However my bet is the problem is in the low RAM or missing code (not shared).